# Changing row data in case it doesn't match different row

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I ran into an issue while was trying to work with a CSV file. Basically, I have a CSV file which contains names and ID's. Header looks something similar to this:

New ID | name | ID that needs to be changed | name |

In the column[0], New ID column, there are numbers from 1 to 980. in the column[3], ID that needs to be changed, there are 714.What I really need to accomplish is to create column[4], which will store ID from column[1] in case name in column[1] is to be found in column[3]. I need to come up with a fucntion which will pick 1 name from column[1], scan whole column[3] to see if that name is there and if it is, ID from columnp[0] is copied to column[4]

So far I got this:

```
import csv
input = open('tbr.csv', "rb")
output = open('sortedTbr.csv',  "wb")
reader = csv.reader(input)
writer = csv.writer(output)

for row in input:
    writer.writerow(row)
    print row

input.close
output.close
```

Which doesn't do much. It writes every single letter into a new column in a csv...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 problems here:

- first you don't specify the delimiter, I assume it's pipe. csv parser cannot autodetect the delimiter.
- second, you create the reader but scan the raw input file instead,
  which explains that when you write the csv back, it creates as many cells as there are letters (iterates over row as `string` type instead of `list`)
- third, when you close your handles, you actually don't call `close` but just access to the method reference. Add `()` to call the methods (classical mistake, everyone gets caught once in a while)

Here's my fixed version for your "extended" question. You need 2 passes, one to read fully column 1 and the other one to check. I use a `dict` to store values and make a relation between name and ID

My code runs in Python 2.7 only but runs in Python 3.4 provided you comment/uncomment the indicated lines

```
import csv
# python 2 only, remove if using python 3:
input_handle = open('tbr.csv', "r")  # don't use input: reserved kw    
output = open('sortedTbr.csv',  "wb")
# uncomment 2 lines below if you're using python 3
#input_handle = open('tbr.csv', "r", newline='')  # don't use input: reserved kw
#output = open('sortedTbr.csv',  "w", newline='')

reader = csv.reader(input_handle,delimiter='\t')
writer = csv.writer(output,delimiter='\t')

title = next(reader) # skip title line
title.append("ID2")  # add column title

db = dict()

input_rows = list(reader)  # read file once
input_handle.close()   # actually calls close!

# first pass
for row in input_rows:
    db[row[1]] = row[0] # relation: name => id

writer.writerow(title)

# second pass
for row in input_rows:
    row.append(db.get(row[3],""))

    writer.writerow(row)

output.close()
```

I used this as `tbr.csv` (should be .tsv since separator is TAB)

```
New ID  name    ID that needs to be changed name
492 abboui jaouad jordan    438 abboui jaouad jordan
22  abrazone nelli  536 abrazone nelli
493 abuladze damirs 736 abuladze damirs
275 afanasjeva ludmila  472 afanasjeva oksana
494 afanasjeva oksana   578 afanasjevs viktors
54  afanasjevs viktors  354 aksinovichs andrejs
166 aksinovichs andrejs 488 aksinovichs german
495 aksinovichs german  462 aleksandra
```

got this in output: note: added one column

```
New ID  name    ID that needs to be changed name    ID2
492 abboui jaouad jordan    438 abboui jaouad jordan    492
22  abrazone nelli  536 abrazone nelli  22
493 abuladze damirs 736 abuladze damirs 493
275 afanasjeva ludmila  472 afanasjeva oksana   494
494 afanasjeva oksana   578 afanasjevs viktors  54
54  afanasjevs viktors  354 aksinovichs andrejs 166
166 aksinovichs andrejs 488 aksinovichs german  495
495 aksinovichs german  462 aleksandra
```

I would say it works. Don't hesitate to accept the answer :)

Comment: Thanks! Clumsy mistakes, by bad... What about if I want to look through entire 4th column to check if it has data from the 2nd column? And in case it does, I want to add 5rd column with data from the 1st?

Comment: I tried this code, but it says that `'maximum recursion depth exceeded\n(offending frame is two down the stack`. Therefore, this code is supposed to check if row[3] == row[1], whereas I need to see if any entry from column[1] is in column[3]

Comment: maximum recursion? Do you happen to run it from pyscripter? it happens sometimes. Just quit & relaunch. For the question within a question, please edit your post, as my answer needs some rework (2 passes, 1 to read column 1 entirely, and 1 to check column 3 values)

Comment: No, I am running it from Eric6 IDE for Linux and restarting it seems not to have any effect on it

Comment: run it from a standard python executable. No reason why it would fail. Trying to solve your question again now :)

Comment: I will mark your answer as the solution, no worries :) but I still have one more question - I've edited your code a little bit. Here is a link for a code - http://www.pastebucket.com/549640 and a link to CSV - http://www.pastebucket.com/549641. You can see in CSV there are similar names but the are not aligned. So what I need is new ID in col[0] of one name to be copied in col[4] next to the exact name in col[3]

Comment: you mean the CSV file you linked to is the input? In that case, please provide an example/sample of the output because I don't get your explanation.

Comment: This is what I am trying to achieve - http://www.pastebucket.com/549715

Comment: You are my savior! Thank you!